# How to get latest status from the table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Below is the table description and insert scripts to load data into the table. I am working on Aurora Mysql database.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS batch;

 CREATE TABLE `Batch` (
      `ID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `StepID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `FileName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `StartDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `EndDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `Status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ETLLoadDate` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The below are the two scenarios where i am getting Success for two. Ideally the status failure for 10 and success for 20.

insert into Batch values(10,10.1,'a.csv','2017-07-06 11:16:07','2017-07-06 11:17:07','FAILED','2017-07-06 11:17:07');
insert into Batch values(10,10.1,'b.csv','2017-07-06 11:18:08','2017-07-06 11:19:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:19:07');
insert into Batch values(10,10.1,'c.csv','2017-07-06 11:19:08','2017-07-06 11:20:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:20:07');
insert into Batch values(10,10.1,'d.csv','2017-07-06 11:20:08','2017-07-06 11:21:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:21:07');
insert into Batch values(10,10.2,'e.csv','2017-07-06 11:21:08','2017-07-06 11:22:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:22:07');
insert into Batch values(10,10.3,'f.csv','2017-07-06 11:22:08','2017-07-06 11:23:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:23:07');

insert into Batch values(20,20.1,'a.csv','2017-07-06 11:16:07','2017-07-06 11:17:07','FAILED','2017-07-06 11:17:07');
insert into Batch values(20,20.1,'b.csv','2017-07-06 11:18:08','2017-07-06 11:19:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:19:07');
insert into Batch values(20,20.1,'c.csv','2017-07-06 11:19:08','2017-07-06 11:20:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:20:07');
insert into Batch values(20,20.1,'d.csv','2017-07-06 11:20:08','2017-07-06 11:21:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:21:07');
insert into Batch values(20,20.2,'e.csv','2017-07-06 11:21:08','2017-07-06 11:22:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:22:07');
insert into Batch values(20,20.3,'f.csv','2017-07-06 11:22:08','2017-07-06 11:23:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:23:07');
insert into Batch values(20,20.1,'a.csv','2017-07-06 11:16:07','2017-07-06 11:17:07','SUCCESS','2017-07-06 11:17:07');

Comment: so do you need last status? `SELECT `Status` FROM batch ORDER BY EndDateTime DESC LIMIT 1` ? question is not clear

Comment: @Strawberry demanding “urgent help” in the question title, not bothered to format code at all, typical “I need” posting without any own attempts shown ...of course this gets downvoted.

Comment: Now I'm confused about which is the correct data set.

Comment: There are above in question insert scripts available for id 10 and 20.

Comment: There's lots of code there. Is all of it relevant?

Comment: Removed irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(a.startdatetime)
              , COALESCE(b.status,a.status) status 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM batch x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT id
                   , stepid
                   , DATE(startdatetime) dt
                   , MAX(startdatetime) max_dt
                FROM batch
               GROUP
                  BY id
                   , stepid
                   , dt
            ) y
           ON y.id = x.id
          AND y.stepid = x.stepid
          AND y.dt = DATE(x.startdatetime)
          AND y.max_dt = x.startdatetime
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM batch x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT id
                   , stepid
                   , DATE(startdatetime) dt
                   , MAX(startdatetime) max_dt
                FROM batch
               GROUP
                  BY id
                   , stepid
                   , dt
            ) y
           ON y.id = x.id
          AND y.stepid = x.stepid
          AND y.dt = DATE(x.startdatetime)
          AND y.max_dt = x.startdatetime
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   AND DATE(b.startdatetime) = DATE(a.startdatetime)
   AND b.status = 'failed'
 WHERE a.status = 'success';
+-----------------------+---------+
| DATE(a.startdatetime) | status  |
+-----------------------+---------+
| 2017-06-21            | SUCCESS |
| 2017-06-22            | FAILED  |
| 2017-06-24            | FAILED  |
| 2017-06-23            | SUCCESS |
+-----------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am not getting correct results for the below two scenario's. Please find insert scripts for ID 10 and 20 above in question window.